# I don't know for sure the sentence is grammatically correct

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-perfect

I have written a sentence that seems to me a little cumbersome because of the uncertain use of verb tenses.

> In the beginning, it had been just a hobby, but more I had been improving in it, more I had been realizing it as a significant part of my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, the verb tenses are a little awkward. There are a few options, here is one:

> In the beginning, it had been just a hobby, but *the* more I improved, *the* more I realized it was a significant part of my life.